# How get an object data in controller from a factory that fetch data with api in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I have a controller with two functions that both of them call me a function in factory :

```
.controller("Ctrl",function($scope,fetchDataFromServer){

  $scope.dataArray = [];
  $scope.dataArray2 = [];

  $scope.addNew = function () {
     fetchDataFromServer.fetchData()
     .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // $scope.dataArray.push(data);
     });
  };

  $scope.addNew2 = function() {
    console.log(fetchDataFromServer.fetchData());
  }

})
```

And I have a factory that fetch data from an api :

```
.factory('fetchDataFromServer', function ($http, $q) {
   return {
      fetchData: function() {

           return $http.get('//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
               .then(function(response) {
                   if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                       return response.data;
                   } else {
                       // invalid response
                       return $q.reject(response.data);
                   }

               }, function(response) {
                   // something went wrong
                   return $q.reject(response.data);
               });
       }
   };
})
```

`console.log` in add addNew give me an object :

> Object { userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt", body: "quia" }

But I give this result in my controller :

> {…}
>   ​
>   "$$state": {…}
>   ​​
>   status: 1
>   ​​
>   value: Object { userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", … }
>   ​​
>   : Object { … }
>   ​
>   : Object { then: then()
>   , catch: catch(), finally: finally(), … }

Can anyone explain for me why results are different and what is the cause of difference?

My code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iJB29STVMp2hqBEBUiyM?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Second function, you are printing promise and first function you are printing resolved value/result of a promise.

```
$scope.addNew2 = function() {
    fetchDataFromServer.fetchData()
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // $scope.dataArray.push(data);
     });
}
```